# Negative Lookahead in a Monadic Parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads, state-monad

I have a monadic parser that I'm implementing as an exercise. Its signature looks like this:

```
type Parser err src target = ExceptT err (State [src]) target
```

I've already implemented many basic helpers, but I've come across a use case where a negative lookahead is necessary. In particular, I think I'd like to make something of this signature:

```
notFollowedBy :: e -> Parser e s t -> Parser e s t' -> Parser e s t
notFollowedBy followedByError parser shouldFail = -- ...
```

My thought is that it can be used in context like this:

```
foo = letter `notFollowedBy'` digit
    where notFollowedBy' = notFollowedBy FollwedByDigitError
```

I'm stumbling to implement `notFollowedBy`, though for a variety of reasons:

- I need a way to run `shouldFail` such that I can invert its ExceptT result (ie. if it throws I want to catch it and do nothing, but if it doesn't throw I need to throw `notFollowedByError`)

  - `catchError` won't do here (I don't think) and I couldn't figure out a way to use `runExceptT` to get the `Either e t'` from `shouldFail`
- Before I run `shouldFail` I need to save the state from `StateT` because after running `shouldFail` I need to restore the state (as if this parser wasn't run). But I'm using the Lazy `StateT`, so it's unclear if I need to switch everything to the strict one just to allow for this case

My best stab doesn't even compile, but it looks like this:

```
notFollowedBy :: (t' -> e) -> Parser e s t -> Parser e s t' -> Parser e s t
notFollowedBy onUnexpected parser shouldFail = do
  parsed <- parser
  state <- get -- This isn't strict
  result <- runExceptT shouldFail -- This doesn't typecheck
  case result of
    Left err -> put state >> return parsed
    Right t -> put state >> throwError $ onUnexpected t
```

(As an implementation note, the first parameter is actually `(t' -> e)`, because I want to allow customizing the error thrown based on information returned by the second parser. But I don't think that matters for my question.)

The typecheck failure is due to it expecting `ExceptT (ExceptT e (State [s])) t` but getting `Parser e s t` (which is `ExceptT e (State [s]) t`).

After pouring over the docs and reading some of the source for ExceptT and StateT, my best guess is that I need to emulate `catchError` (which matches on an `Either`) and then use `liftCatch`. This is my sloppy stab at that (which also doesn't compile):

```
notFollowedBy :: (t' -> e) -> Parser e s t -> Parser e s t' -> Parser e s t
notFollowedBy onUnexpected parser shouldFail = do
    state <- get
    result <- parser
    catchSuccess' result shouldFail (throwError . onUnexpected)
    put state
    return result
  where catchSuccess' result = liftCatch (catchSuccess result)
        catchSuccess r (Left l) _ = Right r
        catchSuccess _ (Right r) h = Left (h r)
```

The typechecker seems to be unhappy about a lot of things the second time around. In particular, it seems like `liftCatch` (from `State.Lazy`) is not what we want (because it expects `catchSuccess'` to return an `ExceptT`).

At this point I'm just flailing around making random permutations trying to appease the compiler. Can anyone offer any suggestions about how I could implement `notFollowedBy`?

**edit:** After consulting how I implemented `optional` (below), it seems like the state ordering is not an issue (although how that is is a mystery to me). So my primary issue then is creating the reverse of `catchError` (`catchSuccessAndSuppressError`).

```
option :: Parser e s t -> Parser e s t -> Parser e s t
option parserA parserB = do
  state <- get
  parserA `catchError` \_ -> put state >> parserB
```

### tl;dr

I'm trying to write a function with this signature that throws `followedByError` when `shouldFail` does not throw an exception (when run after running `parser`). The state upon return should be the same as the state after `parser` is run.

```
type Parser err src target = ExceptT err (State [src]) target

notFollowedBy :: e -> Parser e s t -> Parser e s t' -> Parser e s t
notFollowedBy followedByError parser shouldFail = -- ...
```

Comment: Hint: your parser is monadic. It can pick different effects based on values produced. Try writing `succeeded :: Parser e s a -> Parser e s Bool` in terms of `option`, and then using monadic binding to branch on the result of that.

Comment: Thanks! I like this decomposition. Assuming I didn't have the `(t' -> e)` for producing the error, I see how I could use it: `do { result <- parser; state <- get; didSucceed <- succeeded shouldFail; if didSucceed then put state >> throwError onUnexpected else put state >> return result }` (however I'm still not sure I understand how the `get` isn't just lazily evaluated after `shouldFail`? I can see how `succeeded` probably shouldn't modify the state but even if I push the state restoration into it, I still have the lazy issue I think).

Comment: If `succeeded` did not effect the state, then I could use it like `notFollowedBy = do { result <- parser; didSucceed <- succeeded shouldFail; if didSucceed then throwError onUnexpected else return result }`. For implementing, `succeeded` I think I got it: `succeeded p = do { state <- get; result <- (p >> return True) \`option\` (return False); put state; return result }`. I still am unsure how that preserves the state, but I think it works so thank you! If there's a better way please let me know. Feel free to copy & paste that as an answer and I'll give you the green checkmark!